# Accessing S3 Object with S3 wrapper and shell_exec() PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am using S3 as storage of content for my site. I am able to use S3 object with S3 wrapper to access them. But when I try to use with shell_exec(), it gives me error like...

*s3://{my_bucket}/{object_key}: Protocol not found
Did you mean file:s3://{my_bucket}/{object_key}?*

FYI, I am using it create a thumb from video with ffmpeg command. I also confirmed with my server provider that he installed and configured aws-cli on my server.

What am I doing wrong or missing something in it? Let me know correct way to achieve this.

Here is my code...

```
$vidPath    = "s3://{my_bucket}/{vid_object_key}"; // where {vid_object_key} is path to source video

$thumbPath  = "s3://{my_bucket}/{thumb_object_key}"; // where {thumb_object_key} is path where thumb will be generated

$cmd        = "$ffmpeg -ss 1.0 -i ".$vidPath." -vframes 1 -t 1 ".$thumbPath." 2>&1";

$result     = shell_exec($cmd);
```

Comment: you can't connect through api call?

Comment: I can. However few of my code is running with native PHP file finctions where it uses files' absolute directory path. So I used S3 wrapper. and working fine all around, but with this shell_exec().

Comment: Can you show the code?